# React MovieDB API problem. Setting this.setState twice breaks my component

Tags: ajax, reactjs, jsx

I followed a youtube tutorial using the MovieDB API with React. I can search for movies and pull up a title, description, and movie image. I want to add the ability for a youtube trailer to be played. I have successfully fetched the youtube ID's and store them. I'm having trouble displaying them. If I uncomment in my App.js

```
this.setState({ rows: videoRows });
```

Then the youtube videos work. But my title, description, and movie image are undefined and vice versa.

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import MovieRow from "./MovieRow.js";

import $ from "jquery";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {};
    this.performSearch("woman");
  }

  performSearch(searchTerm) {
    // console.log("perform search");
    const API_KEY = "625914798003ef54176364f32c232968";
    const urlString = `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=${API_KEY}&query=${searchTerm}`;
    const urlVideoString = `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/297762/videos?api_key=${API_KEY}&language=en-US`;

    //fetch generic info
    $.ajax({
      url: urlString,
      success: searchResults => {
        console.log("fetch basic success");
        const results = searchResults.results;
        var videoRows = [];
        var movieRows = [];
        // call next ajax function
        $.ajax({
          url: urlVideoString,
          success: searchResults => {
            console.log("fetch Youtube video key success");
            const results = searchResults.results;

            results.forEach(movie => {
              movie.video_src = movie.key;
              console.log(movie.video_src);

              var videoRow = <MovieRow key={movie.id} movie={movie} />;
              videoRows.push(videoRow);
            });


            //If I run this line below it will break 
            //my generic basic info(title, movie description, and picture) , 
            //but it makes the youtube player work
            // this.setState({ rows: videoRows });
          },



          error: (xhr, status, err) => {
            console.log("failed video fetch");
          }
        });
        results.forEach(movie => {
          movie.poster_src =
            "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185" + movie.poster_path;
          console.log(movie.poster_path);

          const movieRow = <MovieRow key={movie.id} movie={movie} />;
          movieRows.push(movieRow);
        });

        this.setState({ rows: movieRows });
      },

      error: (xhr, status, err) => {
        console.log("failed fetch");
      }
    });
  }
  searchChangeHandler(event) {
    console.log(event.target.value);
    const boundObject = this;
    const searchTerm = event.target.value;
    boundObject.performSearch(searchTerm);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <table className="titleBar">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <img alt="app icon" width="100" src="green_app_icon.svg" />
              </td>
              <td width="8" />
              <td>
                <h1>MoviesDB Search</h1>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <input
          style={{
            fontSize: 24,
            display: "block",
            width: "99%",
            paddingTop: 8,
            paddingBottom: 8,
            paddingLeft: 16
          }}
          onChange={this.searchChangeHandler.bind(this)}
          placeholder="Search for movie by title..."
        />
        {this.state.rows}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

MovieRow.js

```
import React from "react";
import YouTube from "react-youtube";

class MovieRow extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }
  viewMovie() {
    const url = "https://www.themoviedb.org/movie/" + this.props.movie.id;
    window.location.href = url;
  }
  viewTrailer() {
    //const trailerURL = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Q8fG0TtVAY";
  }
  _onReady(event) {
    // access to player in all event handlers via event.target
    event.target.pauseVideo();
  }
  render() {
    const opts = {
      height: "390",
      width: "50%",
      playerVars: {
        // https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters
        autoplay: 1
      }
    };

    return (
      <table key={this.props.movie.id}>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <img alt="poster" width="180" src={this.props.movie.poster_src} />
            </td>
            <td>
              <h1>src {this.props.movie.video_src}</h1>
              <h3>{this.props.movie.title}</h3>
              <p>{this.props.movie.overview}</p>

              <YouTube
                videoId={this.props.movie.video_src}
                opts={opts}
                onReady={this._onReady}
              />
              <input
                className="btn btn-primary"
                type="button"
                onClick={this.viewTrailer.bind(this)}
                value="Play Trailer"
              />
              <input
                className="btn btn-primary"
                type="button"
                onClick={this.viewMovie.bind(this)}
                value="View"
              />
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    );
  }
}

export default MovieRow;
```

Comment: how is App.js and MoviewRow.js connected?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean. I import MovieRow.js in App.js. I just started React this week so how things are connected are vague to me.

Answer (score 0):

I see a lot of problems going on here. One is that row state is not initialized. 
You should always initialize a state on the constructor

```
this.state = {
  row: []
};
```

The other problem I saw is that you shouldn't be storing components in state. 
See this

> State should contain data that a component's event handlers may change to trigger a UI update. In real apps this data tends to be very small and JSON-serializable. When building a stateful component, think about the minimal possible representation of its state, and only store those properties in this.state. Inside of render() simply compute any other information you need based on this state. You'll find that thinking about and writing applications in this way tends to lead to the most correct application, since adding redundant or computed values to state means that you need to explicitly keep them in sync rather than rely on React computing them for you.

What you can do instead is rewriting your state like

```
this.state = {
   movies: []
}
```

And inside your ajax request

```
// Change these lines to 
results.forEach(movie => {
  movie.video_src = movie.key;
  console.log(movie.video_src);

  var videoRow = <MovieRow key={movie.id} movie={movie} />;
  videoRows.push(videoRow);
});

// To this
results.forEach(movie => {
  movie.video_src = movie.key;
  videoRows.push(movie);
});

this.setState({ movies: videoRows });
```

And lastly inside your render method, loop all the movies in your state and and return 
your MovieRow component

```
{this.state.movies.map(movie => <MovieRow key={movie.id} movie={movie}/>)}
```

Comment: I am able to see the **movies** and **rows** in state now with the correct info and arrays. It seems that the **rows** array in the state has a props property that my **movies** row doesn't. My code seems to access the **rows** info using things like "this.props.movie.id" How can I access the array in **movies** row in my MovieRow.js?